# Server rebooting every 5 minutes

Tags: server

I have an Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS and its rebooting every 5 minutes. I checkout some logs (syslog, kernel.log and the last **reboot command**) and there is nothing suspicious.

Anyone has any trick to discover this?

On server has installed a LAMP service, Dovecot and Postfix (mail server).

Logs of **last reboot** command:

```
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-96-generi Mon Sep 26 11:27 - 11:31  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-96-generi Mon Sep 26 11:22 - 11:31  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-96-generi Mon Sep 26 11:17 - 11:31  (00:13)
```

Comment: Do you have a cron job running reboot every 5 minutes?

Comment: No. I checked too.

Comment: Do you think perhaps there is something in the logs between 00:03 and 00:08 that also exists between 00:08 and 00:13 that might give us some clues? If so please [edit] your question to provide a more complete picture of your issue. Otherwise, I for one don't have enough to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have enough time to find more clues, so I did server's backup and restored it. Thanks for all the help.